# avoid space node generate by jstl

Tags: html, css, jstl

I use jstl in xhtml pages with JSF.
However, i notice that when i use jstl tags like foreach, HTML space nodes are generated.

```
                <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="6" step="1">
                    <img src="http://${server.host}:${server.port}/${application.name}/rest/image-processor/get-random-s45/166/93/#{homePageManagedBean.getNextInt()}"/>                
                </c:forEach>
```

How can I avoid html space node generation ? In the following example, space nodes are generated between each img.

I try to set trim space property in servlet init params but it doesn't work:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I am working at pixel size at html level. So html space nodes are pretty disturbing.
Thanks you in advance for your help

Comment: FIxed wraping imgs between  <div style="display:flex;">